# Fetching data from Postgres database in batches

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am using Java to read(SELECT) from Postgres Database using JDBC API.
But the problem is ,the number of rows returned from the query is in millions (approx 600 millions) and I can allot a fixed memory size for the application which is why it is giving "OutOfMemory".

Is there a way to fetch data from DB in batches, like 1000 rows at once and then next 1000 and so on ,so that the data in memory at any time is limited for processing(I have to iterate through the rows for further manipulation)?

Lastly, I have to write the data into a excel sheet after the processing.

Comment: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html#query-with-cursor

Comment: Please add a minimum runnable example of what you are trying to do, or at least what code you have. Also, read "how to ask" on this website.

Comment: @raoul I think the question is quite clear. See the link in the above comment.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I agree that the question is clear. The author would be well advised to show us what efforts he made to solve the problem, though.

Comment: If you must use select then you might consider ending your sql with "limit number offset number"; and update the offset value each time. For the output I don't know Java but in Python I would give up on the Excel and output to CSV which is close, so you may have the same problem in Java